# How to add values from MainActivity to list in SecondActivity

Tags: java, android, list

I have a problem with adding values to list which is in SecondActivity. In MainActivity I set text in EditText boxes and send to second class. For the first time values are adding, but when I back to previous activity and one more time set text and send it, values in the list are replaced, not added. Someone know what is the source of this problem?

Comment: Maybe problem is with closing SecondActivity? I'm using finish(), is it right?

Comment: Make that list static if you want to keep it

Comment: How are you sending data?

Comment: I don´t reccomend you pass the list from the bundle, because if your list is huge that throw an exception and your app crash, like @Lucefer say´s make static to keep it and set null when you don´t use it.

Comment: Ok gr8! I created static list and it works! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

try this in first activity:

```
String[] array = {"Hi", "there", "yeah"};
    Intent goIntent = new Intent(this, NewAppActivity.class);
    /*
    * put extra with "array" as a key and the String[] with your values as the value to pass
    * */
    goIntent.putExtra("array", array);
    startActivity(goIntent);
```

and in second activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String[] array = extras.getStringArray("array");
    }
```